# Passing Form Querystring (custom queryset) to Django Detailview

Tags: django

I have a form:

```
class MyTestForm(forms.Form):

    options = (
        ("1", "deck1"),
        ("2", "deck2"),
        ("3", "deck3"),
        ("4", "deck4"),
        )

    choices = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices = options, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required = False)
```

and a views.py which passes the querystring of the form:

```
class NewFormView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = MyNewForm()
        context = {'form':form }
        return render(request, 'testformv2.html', context)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = MyNewForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data=form.cleaned_data
            base_url = reverse('newcombined', kwargs={'pk':24}) ## change this
            querystring = '{}?'.format(base_url)
            myqueries = [query for query in data if data[query] != []] # take the non-empty selections of the form
            for query in myqueries:
                if len(data[query]) == 1:
                    query_arguement = str(query)+'='+str(data[query][0]) +'&'
                    querystring += query_arguement
                elif len(data[query])>1:
                    query_argument = str(query)+'='+','.join(data[query])+'&'
                    querystring += query_argument
                else:
                    print('error occured for some reason')
            url = querystring[:-1] #takes the last character & sign off
            return redirect(url)


    return render(request, 'testformv2.html', {'form':form})
```

so i will end up with a url that looks like "/v2/test/25/?Decks=2,4" ... my problem is I want to use the querystring filters to filter for a specific queryset, however, i must provide DetailView with a primary key in the URL. I am wondering if i should be processing the queryset in the post request of the form (when the form is submitted), OR if i should get the primary key of one of the objects in the queryset, and THEN get the custom filtered queryset in the DetailView. (my problem is more complicated than this because i have a form on the detailview which uses get_object() function, so i cannot use ListView.